# ¿Cuál es la mejor forma de establecer top para un DELETE usando TRANSACTION?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo miles de registros en una tabla, los cuales, individualmente pesan alrededor de 15 Mb y los estoy eliminando en bloques de 10, todo esto mediante una transacción, pero leyendo un poco más a fondo me he encontrado con el **TRANSACTION LOG**, del cual salen mi dudas:

- Con base al tamaño qué soporte el **TRANSACTION LOG** puedo fiarme para defirmir mi **top** para hacer **DELETE**?
- ¿Cuál es la mejor practica para defirmir un **top** a eliminar y con base a qué?

***Código:***

```
BEGIN TRAN
    WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0
       DELETE TOP 10
          FROM table1
COMMIT TRAN
```

SGBD:
    SQL Server 2016

Comment: ¿Por qué usar bloques de 10?

Comment: Solo por ejemplo, por esa razón lo questiono.

Comment: Si es un proceso que correras a diario o por noche es mejor usar SQL Agent Service, agregas un Stored Procedure de borrado y estableces un horario para ejecucion. Regresando al anterior comentario  Como dice @Zolio por que bloques de 10?.

Comment: La intención es crear un Job y dentro establecer la instrucción de borrado y ejecutarlo cada noche sin perjudicar la operación del sistema que usa la BD, el bloque es para evitar llenar el TRANSACTION LOG.

Comment: ¿el `delete` es la única sentencia dentro de la transacción? si fuera así, la pregunta es ¿por que dentro de una transacción? La idea de hacer lotes de eliminación ¿es por alguna razón en particular?

Comment: Tengo un select dentro de la transacción, después de ese viene el delete. Hacerlo por lotes es para evitar llenar el Log de transacción.

Answer (score 0):

Si tu objetivo es borrarlo todo creo que el enfoque que mas te conviene es usar TRUNCATE TABLE, ¿Lo has valorado? Te vaciará toda la tabla de manera mucho mas eficiente.

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: truncate es total, no permite lotes ni where.

Answer (score 0):

En esta pregunta de [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46385/delete-all-but-top-n-from-database-table-in-sql) se utiliza:

```
delete from TUTABLA where tablaID not in (select top 10 tablaID from TUTABLA )
```

Y @Chris Miller menciona su problema:

> esta consulta tiene un problema potencial. La consulta "SELECT TOP 10" se ejecutará para cada fila de la tabla, lo que podría convertirse en un problema de rendimiento. hay que tratar de evitar hacer la misma consulta de manera reiterada

Recordar que La eliminación de una fila es un proceso similar al de insertar un nuevo registro.

Cuando se ejecuta `delete` siempre es importante pensar en los eventos de registros del TRANSACTION LOG que pueden interrumpir el proceso y generar problemas de bloqueo en la base de datos.

Otra manera de hacer esto es seleccionar los registros a borrar e insertarlos en una tabla, para luego realizar `truncate table` a la tabla involucrada.

```
INSERT INTO tablaParaBorrarRegistros
SELECT top 1000 * FROM table1
WHERE tuCondicion < 1000;

TRUNCATE TABLE tablaParaBorrarRegistros;
```

En este [articulo](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes) del sitio [sqlperformance.com](https://sqlperformance.com) analizan el performance de realizar DELETE por partes en diferentes casos.

Answer (score 0):

El transaction log es una herramienta que permite a SQL Server conocer que es lo que se hace en cada momento y, por lo mismo, sus respaldos ayudan a restaurar una base de datos a cualquier momento en el tiempo. El manejo del log es distinto según el modo de recuperación de la base de datos. En el modo completo, el log sólo se reutiliza después de cada respaldo del log. En el modo simple, se marca como reutilizable al finalizar cada transacción.

Como se menciona en otra respuesta, para borrar todos los datos de una tabla es posible utilizar la instrucción `TRUNCATE TABLE`. Esta instrucción evita que crezca demasiado el log debido a que sólo registra las páginas liberadas y no cada fila de información como lo hace el `DELETE`. Sin embargo, otra restricción de esta instrucción es el que la tabla no puede estar referenciada por llaves foráneas.

En caso de querer hacer un `DELETE` por bloques, es importante que cada instrucción sea una transacción independiente. En el ejemplo que pones, sólo habrá una transacción para todos los bloques, lo que elimina el sentido de hacerlo de esa forma.

Para definir el tamaño de cada bloque, necesitas saber cuantas lineas puede soportar el log sin necesidad de crecer. Se debe tomar en cuenta que puede haber otras instrucciones ejecutándose al mismo tiempo y que también utilizarán el log. Se evita que el log crezca debido a que eso es lo que más recursos consume durante operaciones grandes. También es posible mantener un log de tamaño suficientemente grande para soportar todas las operaciones de rutina y evitar que crezca.

Aaron Bertrand hizo algunas mediciones donde muestra como afecta el tamaño de cada bloque en los tiempos y el tamaño del log. Las puedes encontrar en [este artículo](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes).